# There is a lot of code vs There are a lot of code

Tags: phrase-usage

Which is correct?

> There **is** a lot of code (our program consists of)
>
> There **are** a lot of code (our program consists of)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114186/there-is-a-lot-vs-there-are-lot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "code" is singular in this sentence. It is being used as an uncountable noun. It must have a verb that agrees in number.  You must say "There is a lot of code..."

Somewhat more surprisingly, with plural nouns the agreement is with the plural, not with "lot": "There are a lot of toys". Contrast this with "There is a box of toys"